# Enable GEOLOCATION in WebKit Browser C#

Tags: c#, geolocation, webkit

I'm creating a window form project using Webkit.NET

I set WebKitBrowser URL to " http://htmlfive.appspot.com/static/whereami.html " ( website that uses google map to locate your position )

The messageBox did pop up so I think the browser is trying to resquest permission But I don't know to enable GEOLOCATION in a webkit Browser ?

```
 private void webkit1_GeolocationPositionRequest(object sender, GeolocationRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable Geolocation 
           MessageBox.Show("DONE");
    }
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?